Deriative of algebraic implicit function is algebraic
Let $P(x,y)$ be a real polynomial with $P(0,0)=0$, and assume that $\partial_y P(x,y)$ is nonzero over $[-1,1]^2$. Then the equation $P(x,y)=0$ defines an implicit function $y=f(x)$ near $0$. In this case, we say $f$ is an algebraic function.
My question is: is $f'(x)$ also an algebraic function? Namely, can we find another polynomial $Q(x,y)$ such that $Q(x,f'(x))=0$ for all $x$?

Yes, this is true. Viewing $y$ as a function of $x$, differentiate $P(x,y)$ with regards to $x$ to get an equation of the form $A(x,y)+B(x,y)y'=0$, so that $y'=-\frac{A(x,y)}{B(x,y)}$ inside the field of algebraic functions. Since every element of the field of algebraic functions is algebraic over the field of rational functions, $y'$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients from $\Bbb R(x)$, and clearing denominators we find that $y'$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients from $\Bbb R[x]$.

"every element of the field of algebraic functions is algebraic over the field of rational functions" Thank you so much for your reply! Could you give a reference such as a textbook?

The field of algebraic functions is obtained from the field of rational functions by adjoining roots $y$ of polynomials $P(x,y)$; it follows easily that the field is algebraic, which means every element is algebraic. Consult any basic abstract algebra textbook with a section on field theory for details.
